# Bundling Lit components

Tags: typescript, lit

I'm a bit about confused how I'm supposed to be referencing/importing my Lit components. The components aren't making it into my esbuild bundle, because, well, they aren't referenced.

Suppose I have `ParentComponent` which renders `ChildComponent` via `<child-component>`.

```
export class ParentComponent extends LitElement
{
    protected render(): TemplateResult
    {
        return html`<child-component></child-component>`;
    }
}
```

Forgive the lack of the correct Lit/web components terminology, but being a web component, I assume `<child-component>` is resolved at runtime, but because `ChildComponent` is never imported or referenced, it doesn't get included in the bundle, so `<child-component>` never ends up registered by Lit, and things don't work very well.

If I import `ChildComponent` and do something like the below, `ChildComponent` is bundled and things work:

```
protected render(): TemplateResult
{
    console.log(ChildComponent);
    return html`<child-component></child-component>`;
}
```

What am I supposed to be doing? How can I ensure my components are included in the bundle even though importing `ChildComponent` in the first example would still not have it included in the bundle because it would be unused?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the entry point of your application, import all your components like this:

```js
import "./components/ChildComponent.js";
import "./components/AnotherComponent.js";
// ...
```

Do **not** make it a named import if you are not going to use it:

```js
import ChildComponent from "./components/ChildComponent.js"; // ❌
import { AnotherComponent } from "./components/AnotherComponent.js"; // ❌
```